# Operation type in boost mpi collective operations

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

In `boost::mpi` some collective operations, such as [reduce](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/reduce.html), require an operation to be passed to the routine. I am not sure what exactly should be the type of this operation.

The following minimal example compiles without warnings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpi/collectives.hpp>

int mysum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int main()
{
  boost::mpi::environment env;
  boost::mpi::communicator world;

  int data = world.rank() + 1;
  int data_reduced;
  boost::mpi::reduce(world, data, data_reduced, mysum, 0);
  if (world.rank() == 0)
    std::cout << data_reduced << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However, running with more than 1 task crashes

```
$ mpirun -n 2 ./mpi
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
...
```

Altering the code as follows make the program work without crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpi/collectives.hpp>

struct mysum {
  int operator()(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};

int main()
{
  boost::mpi::environment env;
  boost::mpi::communicator world;

  int data = world.rank() + 1;
  int data_reduced;
  boost::mpi::reduce(world, data, data_reduced, mysum{}, 0);
  if (world.rank() == 0)
    std::cout << data_reduced << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

(I am aware that this is equivalent to [std::plus](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus), the program is just an example)

```
$ mpirun -n 2 ./mpi
3
```

What is the difference, and why is the second version working?

**Edit**

The question also arises because both variants of `mysum` can be called  as `mysum(....)`, i.e., both are [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278424/what-is-a-callable-object-in-c). So in both cases a code like the following works.

```
template <class Callable, class ArgType>
auto dosomething(ArgType a, ArgType b, Callable&& L) { return L(a, b); }

auto x = dosomething(mysum, 1, 2);
```

(This is essentially equivalent to [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is what `boost::mpi` expects!

If you mimic `boost/mpi/operations.h`, your user defined reduction operator can be written like this

```
template<typename T>
struct mysum
{
  typedef T first_argument_type;
  typedef T second_argument_type;
  typedef T result_type;
  const T& operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const
  {
    return x + y;
  }
};
```

and then your reduce invocation will look like that

```
boost::mpi::reduce(world, data, data_reduced, std::plus<int>(), 0);
```

bottom line, even if your `mysum` is the right thing to pass to the plain `C` `MPI_Op_create()`, this is not what `boost::mpi` expects.