# Why can't we directly use lambdas without mentioning its type in some STL containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, class-template

I was working with STL containers, trying to implement custom comparators/predicates, and I realized when giving the predicate as a Functor there seem to be same syntax for all containers, i.e. you just mention the name of the Functor as the respective argument in the template arguments, and bam it works!

Now coming to Lambdas they work fine in containers like in `std::vector`, but not in `std::set` the syntax is really weird. Here is some code related to that

For `std::vector` this works fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a = { 3, 1, 0, 2 };
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int& num1, const int& num2) -> bool {
        return num1 < num2;
    });

    for (const int& num : a)
    {
        cout << num << " ";
    }
}
```

But for `std::set` this doesn't work

```
auto PredicateLambda = [](const pair<int, string>& p1, const pair<int, string>& p2) -> bool {
    if (p1.first != p2.first)
        return p1.first < p2.first;
    else
        return p1.second < p2.second;
};

set<pair<int, string>, PredicateLambda> st;
```

rather, you will have to do

```
set<pair<int, string>, decltype(PredicateLambda)> st(PredicateLambda);
```

I find this really weird considering that type is anyway determined during compile time and manually specifying seems unnecessary. I feel like I'm missing something here, really appreciate if someone can fill the gap on why it is done like this?

P.S. One explanation I had in mind is there is some kind of static-time checking of the type of the predicate but, this brings another question to mind how is type checking done in case of Functors which seems to works fine normally(i.e. just specifying the name of the functor)

---

**Edit**: The intention of the question is not about getting to know the syntax, but rather the reasoning behind the design. The reason is that `std::sort()` essentially needs just a callable object which can compare two values and uses that to sort in-place, whereas `std::set` class has to declare the predicate in its class and hence would also need the type of the object too. When we give Functor's name, we are essentially giving the Class Name(which is like a type) but `PredicateLambda` is an object and hence we use `decltype` to figure its type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using custom std::set comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator)

Comment: The difference between sort and set examples you shown is that sort is a function that accepts lambdas but set on the other hand accepts only types. Thats the reason you need to use decltype.

Comment: @rawrex I'm not looking for the syntax, I already found that, moreover just curious about the reasoning behind this design. Thanks for the link tho!

Comment: `PredicateLambda` in your second example is an object, not a type.   The template argument requires a type, hence need for `decltype` (to obtain the type of `PredicateLambda`) when specifying the type of `st`.

Comment: @Bad_Panda to put it simple, the comparator is a part of a `set`'s type, while `sort` accepts a callable object as an argument.

Comment: @PVRT Yeah my bad, got confused there, my doubt is that essentially in both of them you need some kind of function that can compare the values of the container so just giving the lambda should have done the job, just curious if there is any kind of reasoning to why types are being used here instead?

Comment: @rawrex that makes much more sense, and it makes sense to give the object as an argument to the copy constructor, just a little off-topic prolly but in C++20 giving the type of the object seems to suffice, which is weird since we need the definition of the function too right? Is there any explanation for that?
On top of my head I'm just assuming since lambda is gonna get converted into Functor, knowing the type would do the job?

Comment: C++17 introduced rules related to class template argument deduction, and C++20 (substantially) extended those rules.    The purpose of class template argument deduction is - more or less - what you are seeking - infer the template argument (and therefore the complete instantiation of the template type) from the initialisers used when creating an object.   It's just an evolution based on experience with language features - first the core feature (template class definitions) was introduced then, based on experience using them, the possibility of simplifying their use.

Comment: Peter's comment is the most relevant one here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed up the function template  and the class template. For both cases, for any code to appear, it must be instantiated. Let's look at each case:

The [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is a **[function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)** which accepts the binary-predicate (i.e. [callable compare function/ function objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278424/what-is-a-callable-object-in-c)) as its third parameter.

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
constexpr void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp ); (since C++20)
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here the compiler will try to determine template argument types (i.e. `RandomIt` and `Compare`) from the passed function parameters, so-called  **implicit instantiation** will happen automatically if you do not explicitly mention them.

That means, one could also call the `std::sort` with template parameters (explicit instantiation):

```
const auto compare = [](const int& num1, const int& num2) { ...
std::sort<std::vector<int>::iterator, decltype(compare)>(a.begin(), a.end(), compare);
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Whereas, the [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is a **[class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)**. As long as you do not specify the template parameters here, you will not get a concrete type.

> A class template by itself is **not a type, or an object, or any other entity**. No code is generated from a source file that contains only template definitions. **In order for any code to appear, a template must be instantiated: the template arguments must be provided so that the compiler can generate an actual class** (or function, from a function template).

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,         // optional
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

Here, the `Compare` is optional but part of the `std::set`'s class template type, which can be replaced with the user defined compare function/ callable. Without providing the type of callable, the compiler can not instantiate the version of `std::set` you want.

---

**Further Reads**:

- The [`std::pair` has compare operations defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp). Hence, the `PredicateLambda` is not required in your example code. I hope that it is for demonstration purpose.
- Since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) we have [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/deduction_guides), for a template class, by which one can simply write:

  ```
  #include <set>
  #include <tuple>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std::string_literals;

  std::set st{ std::pair{1, "string"s} }; // st uses the
  ```

  One can also provide own [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides)
- Since [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) lambda expression is default constructible. Hence,
  you may not need to pass the `PredicateLambda` as argument to the `st`, in the newer
  compilers.

  ```
  std::set<std::pair<int, std::string>, decltype(PredicateLambda)> st;
  ```

Comment: At first reading, you appear to be suggesting that a programmer provide deduction guides for `std::set`?  That sounds like a really horrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

The type deduction rules for template classes and functions are different.

You are seeing `std::sort` deduce its arguments, including the predicate, type.

Meanwhile, `std::set` class template type deduction is blocked because you provided a template argument to it.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can use deduction guides:

```
std::set s( {{1, "hello"s}}, PredicateLambda );
```

where the type of `PredicateLambda` is moved into the set.

Back in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can use a function pointer

```
std::set<std::pair<int, std::string>, bool(*)(std::pair<int, std::string> const&)> s(
  {{1, "hello"}}, PredicateLambda );
```

which relies on the fact that a stateless lambda can be implicitly cast into a function pointer with matching signature.

If your predicate is *stateful* (ie, captures stuff), you can use `std::function<bool(std::pair<int, std::string> const&)>` in the type of the `std::set` to store the predicate and not expose its type.

---

Now, in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) we can make your syntax a bit simpler as follows:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

auto PredicateLambda = [](auto& p1, auto& p2) -> bool {
    if (p1.first != p2.first)
        return p1.first < p2.first;
    else
        return p1.second < p2.second;
};

template<auto x>
struct call_t {
  decltype(auto) operator()(auto&&...args)const {
    return x(decltype(args)(args)...);
  }
};


int main() {
  std::set<std::pair<int, std::string>, call_t<PredicateLambda>> st;
  st.insert( {0, "hello"} );
}
```

and now we only mention the template name once, and never use `decltype` on it.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/hqcMoxTbq).